# How do I get a string value from the onCall function in Firebase functions in C#?

Tags: c#, firebase, google-cloud-functions

function is registered as such.

```
const functions_address = functions.region('asia-northeast1');

export const createSessionCookie = functions_address.https.onCall(
  async(data,context) =>{
  const dulation = 60 * 5 * 1000;
  const idToken = data;
  try {
    const sessionCookie = await admin.auth().createSessionCookie(idToken, { expiresIn:dulation });

    return {sessionCookie};
  } catch (error) {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError('internal', error + 'Failed to make a sessionCookie.');
  }

});
```

However, the result of the function call was 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.Object,System.Object]'.
What format is {sessionCookie} in? And how can I retrieve the sessionCookie?

The C# side was called with a function like this.

```
        string idToken = await auth.CurrentUser.TokenAsync(true);
        await func.GetHttpsCallable("createSessionCookie").CallAsync(idToken).ContinueWith(task =>{
            if (task.IsCompletedSuccessfully)
            {
                Debug.Log(task.Result.Data.ToString());
                return task.Result.Data.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                return "";
            }
        });
        return "";
```

And 'task.Result.Data.ToString()' was 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.Object,System.Object]'.

Comment: Instead of logging`task.Result.Data.ToString()`, how about logging the dictionary at `task.Result.Data` to see what it contains?

Comment: @DougStevenson

In that case, it remains the same.
'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.Object,System.Object]'

Answer (score 0):

I looked it up and this is what I found. My apologies for the lack of research.

```
await func.GetHttpsCallable("createSessionCookie").CallAsync(idToken).ContinueWith(task =>{
            if (task.IsCompletedSuccessfully)
            {
                Dictionary<object, object> dataDictionary = task.Result.Data as Dictionary<object, object>;

                if (dataDictionary.TryGetValue("sessionCookie", out object value))
                {
                    Cookie =(string)value;
                }

            }
        });
```